# MySQL : Calculating percentage change from average values of two ranges

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the percentage change between the average value of date range A when compared to date range B.

For example, website has 100 visitors during date range A and 200 visitors during date range B, giving an increase of 100%.

The values are stored in a single table.

**EDIT : The visit values are stored in a single table, URLs are stored in a second table which contains the URL and an id which is used to join the two tables.**

My query as it stands is:

```
SELECT urls.url, DATE_FORMAT(test.timestamp, '%Y %m %d') AS timestamp,
(SELECT test.visits 
 FROM test, urls 
 WHERE test.url_id = urls.id 
 AND urls.url LIKE '%website%' 
 AND test.location LIKE '%gb%' 
 AND test.timestamp >='$startdate' 
 AND test.timestamp <= '$enddate'
) AS visitors1, 

(SELECT test.visits 
 FROM test, urls 
 WHERE test.url_id = urls.id 
 AND urls.url LIKE '%website%' 
 AND test.location LIKE '%gb%' 
 AND test.timestamp >= DATE_SUB('$startdate', INTERVAL
     DATEDIFF('$enddate','$startdate') DAY) 
 AND test.timestamp <= DATE_SUB('$enddate', INTERVAL
     DATEDIFF('$enddate','$startdate') DAY)
) AS visitors2
FROM test, urls 
WHERE test.url_id = urls.id 
AND urls.url LIKE '%website%' 
AND test.location LIKE '%gb%'
```

**EDIT : Corrected errors in example query**

I understand that I need to add something like:

```
(visitors1 - visitors2) / visitors2 *100
```

I'm just not sure where

**EDIT : I'm building a dashboard, the desired output is**

URL | Visits range 1 | Visits range 2 | Percentage change

example.com | 100 | 200 | 100%

Apologies for mistakes in original posting.

Comment: You can do this in mysql, but the query will be fairly unreadable. Can you just write the query (like you have) to return the numbers of visits in periods A and B, and then do (A-B)/B * 100 on the result after it's returned from mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole select inside another `select` where you can than access the result-columns using their aliases.

```
/*Outer select*/
SELECT 
  q.url, q.`timestamp`, q.visitors1, q.visitors2
  , (q.visitors1 - q.visitors2) / (q.visitors2+0.00001) *100 AS percentage
FROM (
/*Inner select*/
SELECT 
  url
  , DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y %m %d') AS `timestamp`      
  , (SELECT visits 
     FROM test t
/*note the use of explicit inner joins*/ 
     INNER JOIN urls u ON (t.url_id = u.id)  
      WHERE url LIKE '%website%' AND location LIKE '%gb%' 
/*instead of >= and <= you can use `between` it's shorter to type.*/
      AND timestamp BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') AS visitors1
  , (SELECT visits 
     FROM pagetest p
     INNER JOIN urls u ON (p.url_id = u.id) 
      WHERE u.url LIKE '%icis%com%' 
        AND p.f_TTFB < p.f_render 
        AND location LIKE '%gb%' 
        AND `timestamp` BETWEEN 
            DATE_SUB('$startdate', INTERVAL DATEDIFF('$enddate','$startdate') DAY) 
        AND DATE_SUB('$enddate', INTERVAL DATEDIFF('$enddate','$startdate') DAY)) 
    AS visitors2
FROM test
/* looks like you've got a missing join in the above FROM clause */ 
WHERE url_id = id AND url LIKE '%website%' AND location LIKE '%gb%'
/*Note that you need to supply each inner select with an alias*/
) AS q
/*I've used "q" here*/
```

A note, please don't use implicit SQL'89 join syntax, use explicit SQL'92 joins instead. 
They are much easier to debug because the join criteria and the filter criteria are not mixed together.

Comment: Thanks Johan - I'm just trying to work with your example now. I don't think I helped myself by making a mistake in the example I gave (rookie mistake!)